# Name for a number generator method

Tags: random, methods, conceptual

Suppose I am developing an algorithm that needs a number that must be between two numbers and for those values it must always yield the same number. I moved that calculation to a new method because I use it repeated times.

My friend proposed I should call it "randomBetween(min, max)" but I argue that this would not be correct because it always returns the same value if I send the same arguments, so it isn't random.

Am I wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return the same number for the same arguments, your function is not a random number generator, it's just a mathematical function.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it `deterministicRandomBetween(min,max)`, which captures the repeatability aspect.

However, this doesn't really sound like a general-purpose function.  I can't imagine ever needing this, other than for the specific algorithm you are creating.  So, it might make more sense to give it a name specific to its role in the algorithm (whatever that may be).

Answer (score -1):

you can take the mean value of given numbers.

```
function int  mean(int x, int y)
{
   return (x+y)/2
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the question.